# C# How to make some method called at program startup

Tags: c#, mono

How can I make some method get called when program startup in C# (mono). e.g.

fileA.cs

```
class some_class_a: IWorker {
    void should_be_called_at_startup() {
        ClassFactory.Instance.RegisterClass(myguid, myCreator);
    }
}
```

fileB.cs

```
class some_class_b: IWorker {
    void should_be_called_at_startup() {
        ClassFactory.Instance.RegisterClass(myguid, myCreator);
    }
}
```

And I don't wanna explicit reference to "some_class_a.should_be_called_at_startup" or "some_class_b.should_be_called_at_startup", since the caller don't know whether these files(classes) are exist or not.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked into reflection? You could define which methods are called in the config file

Comment: Reflection won't help here. It sounds like you're looking for an OS-level hook that invokes the method when the program is started. Do you need to know *when it starts* or *that it's running*?

Comment: Reflection is a fine option. In your application's startup code, loop through the objects to call from the config file and run them.

Comment: This is also a good problem that Dependency Injection likes to fix, coupled with Inversion of Control. You can have an Interface IRunAtStartup with a method Execute(), some code that reads a config file and generates a list of IRunAtStartup objects, loop through and call Execute() on each one. You'd need to use reflection to do this. The classes that get instantiated and executed, however, need to either (a) be referenced to the current running DLL or (b) dynamically loaded at runtime -- this gets tricky and complicated and would only be necessary if you must run truly dynamic operations.

Comment: The real question is if you control startup code or not (App vs library). Trivial to call well-known code from startup code, more or less impossible to magically know about when program start if all your code is in DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The CIL (Common Intermediary Language) only allows one entry point on each assembly so you can't start automatically without adding some code on you classes constructors or on the Main method.

The best approach should be creating an Interface `IRunAtStartup` and use reflection on your application entry point (Main/constructors) to find all implementations and run, as @DavidKhaykin have said.

Take a look:

```
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )            // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly HelloCLR
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices...
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices...

  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.module HelloCLR.exe
// MVID: {14AAFB90-AC8E-4A34-84CB-1B9D2888C6E2}
.imagebase 0x00400000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00000001    //  ILONLY
// Image base: 0x032C0000


// =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit HelloCLR
   extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
 .method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
 {
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       23 (0x17)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Hello CLR {0}!"
  IL_0006:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Version 
                      [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_Version()
  IL_000b:  callvirt   instance string 
                      [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
  IL_0010:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(
                      string, object)
  IL_0015:  nop
  IL_0016:  ret
 } // end of method HelloCLR::Main

 .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
     instance void  .ctor() cil managed
 {
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  ret
 } // end of method HelloCLR::.ctor

} // end of class HelloCLR

// =============================================================
// *********** DISASSEMBLY COMPLETE ***********************
// WARNING: Created Win32 resource file C:\herong\HelloCLR_dis.res
```